# Cannot manage to open a specific Linux Fedora port to allow access from other computer via browser?

Tags: linux, exception, localhost, port, fedora

I am new to linux so don't shoot down my question.

I have installed a computer with Linux Fedora 21 Server with Apache, MySQL and PHP so it can run as a webserver. All my webpages work perfectly from other computer by typing in the ip address of my Linux server.

The problem at this moment is that I have installed a web application that runs on port 5000. When I run it locally (localhost:5000) there are no problems, but when I run it from another computer [IP ADDRESS]:5000 it doesn't work. I have added tcp/udp port 5000 to the firewall exceptions and restarted httpd.service with no results.

I have tried several options via the iptables but that also came back without any result.

Please help me out on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what was causing the prevention of accessing my web application on the server remotely. I did open the port in the firewall on tcp and udp, but what I have missed was that I only did this for the permanent state and not for the runtime state to.

So after a restart of the server or adding the open port to the runtime state I was able to access the port from another computer.

Answer (score 0):

@iJar mostly your application running on localhost i.e 127.0.0.1 with port 5000.
so It might reason you are not able to access from other computer. so you need to run your application on 0.0.0.0 with port 5000

For cross check please use below command

```
      netstat -ntulp | grep -i 5000
```

Comment: I have done that and this is the result.
`root@localhost lib]# netstat -ntulp | grep -i 5000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19418/node `

Comment: so I gues it is already listening to 0.0.0.0, right?

Comment: Yes your applications already running on 0.0.0.0. Please run telnet iPaddress ofserver 5000 from other computer

Comment: It states it cannot connect with this server. `Could not open connection to the host, on port 5000: Connect failed'

Comment: Have you tried to flash iptables rules